# React Router : Sidebar displayed in Login Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to hide my sidebar on my login page, only logged user can see it, This is my code but i don't know how to hide it..

```js
 <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="container">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="main_content">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/list" element={<Contrats />} />
              <Route path="/new_contract" element={<AddContract />} />
              <Route path="/edit_contract/:id" element={<EditContract />} />
              <Route path="/contract/:id" element={<Contract />} />
              <Route path="/settings" element={<div>Settings</div>} />
              <Route path="/profile" element={<div>Profile</div>} />
              <Route path="/forbidden" element={<Forbidden />} />
              <Route path="/error" element={<ServerError />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to hide it for no-authorized users ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let pathName = window.location.pathname
let arr = pathName.toString().split("/");
let currentPath = arr[arr.length-1];
 <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="container">

          currentPath.length>0&&<Sidebar />
          <div className="main_content">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/list" element={<Contrats />} />
              <Route path="/new_contract" element={<AddContract />} />
              <Route path="/edit_contract/:id" element={<EditContract />} />
              <Route path="/contract/:id" element={<Contract />} />
              <Route path="/settings" element={<div>Settings</div>} />
              <Route path="/profile" element={<div>Profile</div>} />
              <Route path="/forbidden" element={<Forbidden />} />
              <Route path="/error" element={<ServerError />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Hi, can yo explain please ? what does your code do ?

Comment: suppose your current url is localhost:3000/list so in this case :
Your pathName would be "list"
and your , arr would be ["list"] ,
therefore , currentPath would be "list"
and its length is greater than 0 , so in this case , sidebar would be shown

Comment: But , when your url will be localhost:3000/ , in this case :
pathName would be empty string , 
so , arr would be empty arr [] ,
so , currentPath would be empty ,
there fore currentPath.length is now 0 , so sidebar component won't be shown

Comment: I hope you understood ,what I am trying to say

Comment: It works! thank you..I think there is another solution more cleaner than yours but thank you!! Marked as answer :)

Comment: Which solution is more cleaner ? I also want to learn that one , can you please write it in the comments below

Comment: I found an article that mention that we can use PrivateRoute..

Comment: Please share it , so that I can also refer and learn something new . Thanks

Comment: Post from the other answer : https://ui.dev/react-router-protected-routes-authentication
I will try it also and see if it will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way to do it would be with a simple ternary, like so:

```js
{user.isAuth ? 
 (<Sidebar />) : 
 <></>
}
```

But I'm guessing a cleaner solution could be  using a layout for authenticated routes and an other for the other routes.

Check out [this post](https://ui.dev/react-router-protected-routes-authentication) for something like that

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured out how to do it was rendering it inside my private route component which uses my Auth Context to evaluate wether the user is logged or not, so like:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from '../Contexts/AuthContext';
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';

const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);
return auth.isLogged ? (
  <>
    <SideMenu />
    {props.children}
  </>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/" />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```